# Group a pandas dataframe by one column OR another one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is my dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['name1', 'name2', 'name1', 'name3'],
                    'rate' : [1,2,2,3],
                    'id' : range(4)})

   id   name  rate
0   0  name1     1
1   1  name2     2
2   2  name1     2
3   3  name3     3
```

I want to group the rows of a pandas dataframe if they have the same values in column `name` OR in column `rate`.

```
          id            name       rate
0  [0, 1, 2]  [name1, name2]  [1, 2, 2]
1        [3]           name3        [3]
```

I have a huge dataframe so I don't want to iterate over each row (unless that the only solution). What should I do ?

(I can use Numpy arrays instead of Pandas dataframe)

Comment: I think you'll have to use something like a graph connected-component algorithm, as your requirement is unboundedly-transitive.

Comment: df.groupby(['name', 'rate'])

Comment: @AmiTavory could you give an example ? (or external sources)

Comment: @cnicollet that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @mitsi Yeah, I'll add an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions are unboundedly transitive. Say in rows *2i, 2i + 1* the name is shared and in rows *2i + 1, 2i + 2* the rate is shared, you need to keep linking rows.

One way to solve this is using the [graph theory's connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)).

[image]

For this you can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/). In code, it could be as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.id)
G.add_edges_from(
    [(r1[1]['id'], r2[1]['id']) for (r1, r2) in itertools.product(df.iterrows(), df.iterrows()) if r1[1].id < r2[1].id and (r1[1]['rate'] == r2[1]['rate'] or r1[1]['name'] == r2[1]['name'])]
)
```

Let's create a `group` column, indicating, for each row, its group:

```
df['group'] = df['id'].map(
    dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(ee, i) for ee in e] for (i, e) in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))])))
>>> df.group
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
```

Now you just need to `groupby` the group column, and apply a `list`.

Comment: I really like this answer !
To reduce its readibility tho i'll use : `[(r1['id'], r2['id']) for (_, r1), (_, r2) in itertools.combinations(df.iterrows(), 2) if (r1['rate'] == r2['rate'] or r1['name'] == r2['name'])]` in `add_edges_from`