# Pandas group by either column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the groups (rather than the grouping variable) in a pandas groupby. Here is an example:

```
Name    Col1    Col2    Col3
John    1       A       C
Sam     1       B       C
Mike    1       B       D
Kate    2       E       G
Fred    3       E       H
Liz     3       F       H
Jane    4       X       Y
Henry   4       Z       T
```

If I group then using `Col1 and (Col2 or Col3)`, the corresponding groups  will be

```
output = [['John', 'Sam', 'Mike'], ['Kate'], ['Fred', 'Liz'], ['Jane'], ['Henry']]
```

because a group consists of people having the same `Col1` values, as well as either the same Col2 or the same Col3 value.

I was able to get what I want by creating a graph and finding connected components. Grouping by `Col1` first, then finding connected components is another idea. However, I believe there must be a simpler way.

I would also like to do this in a more general case, such as grouping by `Col1 and Col2 and (Col3 or Col4) and (Col5 or Col6)`.

Comment: I didnt quite understand, what you want exactly, would you mind showing your wanted end result?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the goal. Does `[['John', 'Sam', 'Mike'], ['Kate'], ['Fred', 'Liz']]` constitute your desired output? Could you also share a code snippet of what you mean by "grouping using `Col1 and (Col2 or Col3)`".  How is that different from simply using `df.groupby(['Col1'])['Name']`?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading example. I added two more rows. The desired output can be in any form, like the one I gave as a list of lists. John and Sam are in the same group, because they have the same Col1 and Col2 value. Sam and Mike are in the same group, because they have the same Col1 and Col3 value. John and Mike are in the same group, because they share one connection, Sam. The last two rows are not in the same group, because their Col2 and Col3 values are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look around, and this question is effectively a duplicate of this post:
[Group a pandas dataframe by one column OR another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918268/group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-one-column-or-another-one). So, I cannot - not remotely - take credit for the following solution, but let me just show how you can adjust the impressive answer provided there by [@AmiTavory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49919339/18470692) to suit your specific needs:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.Name)
G.add_edges_from(
    [(r1[1]['Name'], r2[1]['Name']) 
     for (r1, r2) in itertools.product(df.iterrows(), df.iterrows()) 
     if r1[1].Name < r2[1].Name and 
     (r1[1]['Col1'] == r2[1]['Col1'] and 
      (r1[1]['Col2'] == r2[1]['Col2'] or r1[1]['Col3'] == r2[1]['Col3']))]
)

df['group'] = df['Name'].map(
    dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(ee, i) for ee in e] 
                                        for (i, e) in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))])))

# finally, we only need to add this to get the list with nested lists
# containing the names.
output = df.groupby('group')['Name'].apply(list).values.tolist()
output

# [['John', 'Sam', 'Mike'], ['Kate'], ['Fred', 'Liz'], ['Jane'], ['Henry']]
```

In order to achieve other combinations of `and/or`, you will just have to rewrite this bit:

```
     (r1[1]['Col1'] == r2[1]['Col1'] and 
      (r1[1]['Col2'] == r2[1]['Col2'] or r1[1]['Col3'] == r2[1]['Col3']))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood of your question you want to formulate, a list of what it seens to be your index of each individual of your grouped data, for that you will need groups.

So first lets grab your groups names and indexes.

```
df.groupby('col1').groups
```

That is we gonna return a dict whose keys are the names of each group in the columns used and indexes well they are the index of dataframe which is what you want.
After utilizing this groups keys, try doing the following comprehension

```
[v.to_list() for v in df.groupby('col1').groups.values()]
```

That will  return you wanted output independtly from what column you groupby